# Robot framework ImapLibrary: 'quoted-printable' is not a text encoding

Tags: imap, robotframework, imaplib, quoted-printable

I'm getting this LookupError when I try to use `Get Links From Email` keyword:

```html
Open Mailbox  server=imap.googlemail.com  user=user@mail.com  password=pass ${proWelcomeMail} =    Wait for Email  recipient=${USER_EMAIL}  subject=Welcome
Open Link From Email  ${proWelcomeMail}
...
Close Mailbox
```

Output:

```html
ImapLibrary . Get Links From Email ${proWelcomeMail}
LookupError: 'quoted-printable' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

Is there a workaround for this please?

Comment: maybe using updated version 2 resolve this problem https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the library's code by yourself because it's not fixed by the maintainer. Change the line 135 in file **init**.py "decode('quoted-printable')" to "decode('utf-8')".

Comment: @KonstantinV there's a long-standing PR to fix this issue, you can copy the code from there - https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-imaplibrary/pull/9/files. Regretfully the library doesn't look maintained, so that fix might not come in a release.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fork **ImapLibrary2** which has fixed it already
https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary2/